# Attach the PyDev interactive debugger to Python code running in PyXLL

Tags: eclipse, pydev, canopy, pythonpath, pyxll

(In Windows 10, I have installed `...\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy` that includes `Python 2.7`, and another `...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35` that includes `Python 3.5`. `%PATH` points to Canopy)

I want to make "attaching the PyDev interactive debugger to Python code running in PyXLL" work by following [this link](https://www.pyxll.com/alldocs.html#document-examples/developertools) and [this link](http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html).

So I have done the following:

1. saved `eclipse_debug.py` in the folder `...\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages\pyxll\examples\`, and made `pyxll.cfg` include `eclipse_debug.py`
2. added `eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.5.4.201601292234/pysrc` to `%PATH` (`echo %PATH` does show this path, whereas `echo %PYTHONPATH%` still returns `%PYTHONPATH%` in a command prompt)
3. added `import pydevd;pydevd.settrace()` to the `hello` function, which worked before in Excel (`hello("abc")` did return `Hello, abc`).
4. reloaded PyXll in Excel

However, as a result,

1. `hello` function does not work anymore
2. there is no new menu item as promised by `This module adds an Excel menu item to attach to the PyDev debugger, and also an Excel macro so that this script can be run outside of Excel and call PyXLL to attach to the PyDev debugger.` Therefore, I don't know how to debug.

Could anyone help?

[image]

PS: my quess is that `pvdevd` is not well inserted in the environment, because when I type `import` in the code, `pydevd` is not automatically suggested as packages such as `numpy` or `numbers`. But I am really confused with controlling `PYTHONPATH` or `PATH` inside Eclipse.

**Edit 1:**

I have set `PYTHONPATH` in the control panel of Windows to be `...eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.5.4.201601292234/pysrc`. As a result, `echo %PYTHONPATH%` still returns this path in a command prompt. And the `pydevd` is auto-completing in eclipse.

With the following code, without using `eclipse_debug.py`, and after launching `debug server`, the execution breaks just after the line of `settrace`:

```
from pyxll import xl_func
@xl_func("string name: string")
def hello(name):
    import pydevd;pydevd.settrace()
    return "Hello, %s" % name
```

Now, I want to follow the way of `eclipse_debug.py`. I have done the following:

1) erase `PYTHONPATH` in the control panel of Windows (so, I want to rely on `eclipse_debug.py` to find the path)

2) modify only the first line of [eclipse_debug.py](https://www.pyxll.com/alldocs.html#debugging-with-eclipse-and-pydev) to be `eclipse_roots = [r"C:\my_path_to\eclipse"]`.

3) add `eclipse_debug.py` to `pyxll.cfg`

4) use the following code to define the function `hello`:

```
from pyxll import xl_func
@xl_func("string name: string")
def hello(name):
    return "Hello, %s" % name
```

5) launch `debug server` of eclipse, and then launch Excel, and then reload PyXLL

However, no menu item about debug appears in Excel, although the `hello` function works in Excel. Is there something wrong about my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than modifying the `PYTHONPATH` or `PATH` at the environment level, simply do `import sys;sys.path.add(r'< full path to>eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.5.4.201601292234/pysrc')` above the `import pydevd;pydevd.settrace()`

So you should end up with:

```py
import sys
sys.path.add(r'< full path to>eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.5.4.201601292234/pysrc')
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace()
```

To answer some of your related issues:

- Python (AFAIK) does not ever look in `PATH` for python modules. That is what [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) is for. At start-up Python will set `sys.path` to the contents of `PYTHONPATH` + any other settings.
- The `pydevd` not auto-completing was most likely because you PyDev does not know about the modifications you made or intended to make to `PYTHONPATH`. You can tell PyDev by modifying the interpreter settings.
- The [`eclipse_debug.py`](https://www.pyxll.com/alldocs.html#debugging-with-eclipse-and-pydev) is intended to ease the connection to the debugger. You should use the `eclipse_debug.py` method or the above method. However if you use `eclipse_debug.py` you must update the paths near the top of the file.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did make the version without using `eclipse_debug.py` work. However, as I added to my OP, using `eclipse_debug.py` still does not work for me. Could you help?

Comment: You really should ask another question rather than substantially editing the original. I am/was able to answer the original question, but I don't think I will have time to debug your debugging issue with eclipse_debug.py. You will more likely get a quality answer by asking a shorter question that distills your problem with eclipse_debug.py and what you have tried (e.g. can you make any menu item appear or is it just eclipse_debug's one that is missing? Does pydev_src in eclipse_debug.py resolve properly? etc)